# ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories

Tags: mapping, chainlink, brownie, interfaces, configuration

I'm trying to compile a "FundMe.sol" contract: the issue is that when I try to compile it I keep getting the following Compiler Error:

```
Brownie v1.19.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

New compatible solc version available: 0.8.0
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.0
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
  --> contracts/FundMe.sol:15:1:
   |
15 | import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The contract is included inside of the "contracts" folder (initted by brownie), moreover I have created the "brownie-config.yaml" file which should remap @chainlink - I feel as it might have contain some kind of error aswell.

I'm including all the mentioned files down below:

**Project Folder**: [brownie_fund_me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEeeo.png)

**FundMe.sol**:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
//Last update: 25/12/2022

/* ***** ABI = Application Binary Interface *****
 * Interfaces compile down to an ABI. 
 *
 * ABI tells Solidity and other coding languages
 * how it can interact with other contracts. 
 *
 * Anytime you want to interact with another
 * deployed contract, you will need that contracts' ABI.
 */

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

// ***** Imports *****
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";   //The following library is shown below
/*
 *
 *      interface AggregatorV3Interface 
 *      {
 *       function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
 *
 *       function description() external view returns (string memory);
 *
 *       function version() external view returns (uint256);    <-------------- Version
 *
 *       function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId) external view returns 
 *       (
 *           uint80 roundId,
 *           int256 answer,          
 *           uint256 startedAt,
 *           uint256 updatedAt,
 *           uint80 answeredInRound
 *       );
 *
 *       function latestRoundData() external view returns 
 *       (
 *           uint80 roundId,
 *           int256 answer,             <---------- Value in USD
 *           uint256 startedAt,
 *           uint256 updatedAt,
 *           uint80 answeredInRound
 *       );
 *      }
 *
 */

// ***** FundMe *****
// The following contract allows the end users to send a minimum amount
// of ETH without being able to retrive it.
// This contract is a good example of crowd funding.
contract FundMe{
    
    // ***** AddressToAmountFunded *****
    // The following mapping allows the user to access the amount funded
    // by somebody, provided the address.
    mapping (address => uint256) public AddressToAmountFunded;

    // Array of addresses where the address of each funder will be stored in a temporary way
    // Every time the owner calls the withdraw function, the array is being reset
    address[] public funders;

    // Owners' address: this will be the only address being able to withdraw
    address public owner;

    // Constructor is called automatically and istantly when the contract is being deployed
    // Such thing allows the deployer of the contract to be the owner
    constructor() public
    {
        owner = msg.sender;     // msg.sender is who calls a function, in the constructor case, who deploys the contract
    }

    // ***** onlyOwner *****
    // The following modifier is used in the declaration of functions, such as withdraw, 
    // in order to allow the function, to be called only by the owner.
    modifier onlyOwner
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);      // Whoever calls the function (msg.sender) must be the owner
        _;                                 // The "_;" means that we call the instruction after we check that the address of the caller is equal to owner
    }

    // ***** fund *****
    // The following function allows the users to fund the contract with a minimum amount of money "minimumUSD"
    // to this date (25/12/2022) 50$ = 0,041ETH = 41000000000000000Wei = (41 * 10^15)Wei - to update the value, check the USD/ETH change and convert to Wei here https://eth-converter.com/
    // If the amount funded is <= minimumUSD the transaction will not go through and will lead to an inversion of the
    // transaction
    // ! ! ! ! ! Please notice that the amount funded cannot be retrived in any way ! ! ! ! !
    function fund() public payable
    {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 41 * 10 ** 15;                                                                                        // Minimum amount transferable
        require(msg.value >= minimumUSD, "The amount of ETH you sent is less then 50$ - Transaction is being inverted");           // "msg.value" is a keyword that stays for the amount of Wei sent

        AddressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;             // Given an address, the mapping will return the amount funded by such account - Note that these values will be reset every time withdraw is called
        funders.push(msg.sender);                                   // The funders' address will be added to the funders array - Note that these values will be reset every time withdraw is called
    }

    // ***** getVersion *****
    // The following function is contained inside of the imported library AggregatorV3Interface
    // When called, the function will return the current version of the contract/library AggregatorV3Interface
    // ! ! ! ! ! This function will only work if the ENVIROMENT used is local (METAMASK) - JVMs will not return any value and will lead to a possible error ! ! ! ! !
    function getVersion() public view returns(uint256)
    {      
        return AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e).version();     // .version method is contained inside of AggregatorV3Interface, the address can be find here
        //                                                                                                                                                                                 |
        // The function works also if written like this:                                                                                                                                   |
        // AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);  <--- Address                                                              |
        // return priceFeed.version();                                                                           <--- ABI                                                                 /
        // You can find the Addresses for AggregatorV3Interface here ---> https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses/ <----------------------------------------------------
    }

    // ***** getPrice *****
    // The following function is contained inside of the imported library AggregatorV3Interface
    // When called, the function will return the current value of 1ETH in USD, please note that you will get an apporximate value 
    // ! ! ! ! ! This function will only work if the ENVIROMENT used is local (METAMASK) - JVMs will not return any value and will lead to a possible error ! ! ! ! !
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256)
    {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);    // .latestRoundData method is contained inside of AggregatorV3Interface, the address can be found above
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();                                                      // The method returns 5 different values, we exclude all of them but answer, for further understanding check at AggregatorV3Interface under imports
        return uint256(answer / 10 ** 8);                                                                       // Answer is divided by 10^8 so that the value in USD has no decimals and is easier to read
        
        // Historical:
        // 23/12/2022 - 1,226.67395017
        // 25/12/2022 - 1,220.00000000
    }

    // ***** getConvertionRate *****
    // The following function could be considered an extension of getPrice : given
    // the amount of ETH, the function will return the current value of such amount of ETH
    // in USD
    // ! ! ! ! ! This function will only work if the ENVIROMENT used is local (METAMASK) - JVMs will not return any value and will lead to a possible error ! ! ! ! !
    function getConvertionRate(uint256 ETH_Amount) public view returns(uint256)
    {
        uint256 ETH_Price = getPrice();                         // Calls getPrice function
        uint256 ETH_AmountInUSD = ETH_Price * ETH_Amount;       // Current ETH pirce * ETH amount
        return ETH_AmountInUSD;                                 // Returns the value of amount ETH in USD
    }

    // ***** withdraw *****
    // The following function allows the deployer of the contract (owner) to withdraw
    // the amount of ETH funded to the contract, moreover when the function is called,
    // the funders array will be reset
    function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public                // Check for onlyOwner modifier description at line 77
    {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);    // This line of code allows the withdrawal, this refers to the contract

        for(uint256 funderIndex = 0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++)   // The following cycle allows the reset of the money
        {                                                                           // value sent by the funders, accessible through mapping
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            AddressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }

        funders = new address[] (0);                            // funders array gets reset, so that it's able to store new values starting from 0
    }
}
```

**brownie-config.yaml**:

```
dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo@version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.5.1
  
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink = smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.5.1'
```

I'm quiet new to "python-solidity" coding, but so far I had managed to overcome all the issues that were popping up. I have spent over 2 days tring to find a solution to this problem - it's becoming really frustrating. I'm really thankful to whoever - at least - tries helping me!

**Solutions I tried:**

-Changing versions of pragma solidity, imports and repo;

-Adding a .vscode folder --> setting.json containing a path to solidity remappings;

-Updating solc and brownie

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an older version, this one worked for me : @1.1.1

So re run the following commande:

> brownie pm install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1

and then in **brownie-config.yaml** :

```
dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

**FundMe.sol** :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

This worked for me, i hope the same for you

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer - it's telling me that the package is already installed which seems quiet wiered

Comment: @waterlilyjack i updated the answer, hope it will help

Comment: I have tried again and I found out by typing `brownie pm list` that I not only had `smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1` but also @0.2.1 and @0.5.1 - such thing was maybe causing not detected "NameCollision error". Unfortunately, after i got rid of them, it still doesn't work, I'm currently getting crazy trying to find an answer in two other discussion and in Juan Blanco's remapping documentation. I have also re introduced the `setting.json` file that - of course - isn't helping.

Comment: The discussions are the following one: [discussion_one](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/issues/5)

Comment: [discussion_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306209/imports-for-chainlink-and-openzeppelinn-are-broken)

Comment: did you fix the issue ?

Comment: unfortunately, I still haven't figured out what the problem is...